# Calculate the matrices $[{A{π \over 4}]}^v$ for all possible values of v

Tags: matrices, exponential-function

Calculate the matrices $[{A{π \over 4}]}^v$ for all possible values of $v$, when $A(\varphi)=\left(\begin{matrix} \cos\varphi &\sin\varphi\\ -\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi\end{matrix}\right)$ .

So $A\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} &\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\ -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\end{matrix}\right)$. I tried to calculate $ A^v$ for $v=[0,4]$, $v\in Z$ with the hope that it would be a periodical function but this method wasn't fruitful.

*Note:*The question doesn't state that $ v\in Z$ but I guess it should.

Comment: I edited your question to make the $\LaTeX$ render properly by surrounding it with "$$" signs. Remember, to get mathjax to work here you need to enclose your $\LaTeX$ with "$" signs.  Check my edits to see what I mean.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there was a typo in the OP (couldn't tell until the formatting got fixed). Surely it should be $A(\phi)=\binom{\ \cos\phi\,\, -\sin\phi}{\sin \phi\,\,\cos\phi}$. Assuming so:

Hint: This is a funny case where calculating $A(\phi)^\nu$ is easier than $A(\pi/4)^\nu$, because you can see the pattern easier.

In fact the thing to do is this: Calculate the product $A(\phi)A(\theta)$. Now review the sum formulas for sine and cosine, and use them to rewrite your answer for $A(\phi)A(\theta)$. The answer to the original question should now be clear...

Comment: Sorry but still it's not realy clear...

Comment: What did you get for $A(\phi)A(\theta)$? (And what are the sum formulas for sine and cosine?)

Comment: Oops. I believe there was a typo in your post - see my edit for what I conjecture $A(\phi)$ was supposed to be. Look up the problem. _Now_ calculate $A(\phi)A(\theta)$. If you don't get something that reminds you of the sum formulas for sine and cosine you did it wrong. (Regarding what's clear and what isn't: You _do_ have to actually work out that product! It's not _going_ to be clear until you do that.)

Comment: Well...the original function is $A(\varphi)=\left(\begin{matrix} \cos\varphi &\sin\varphi\\ -\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi\end{matrix}\right)$. So $A(\varphi)A(\vartheta)=\left(\begin{matrix} \cos\varphi &\sin\varphi\\ -\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} \cos\vartheta &\sin\vartheta\\ -\sin\vartheta & \cos\vartheta\end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: After multiplication I get $\left(\begin{matrix} \cos\varphi\cos\vartheta-\sin\varphi\sin\vartheta & \sin\vartheta\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi\cos\vartheta\\ -\sin\varphi\cos\vartheta-\sin\vartheta\cos\varphi & -\sin\varphi\sin\vartheta+\cos\varphi\cos\vartheta\end{matrix}\right)=A(\varphi + \vartheta)$ .

Comment: $A(\phi)A(\theta)=A(\phi+\theta)$: right. So $A(\phi)^2=A(\phi+\phi)=A(2\phi)$. And $A(\phi)^3=A(\phi)^2A(\phi)=A(2\phi+\phi)=A(3\phi)$. Etc. And your problem is solved... Don't forget the little arrow...